# How to show progressbar with blurry background and disabled UI

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, onclicklistener, blur

so I am making an app which has a lot of connections to the database, so there is a "waiting" time everywhere.

I want to put a progress bar everywhere where is a connection to the database. It should look like this: 
-The progress bar is shown after clicking the Login button with the blurry background.

In short - Show progress bar, blur the background, deactivate UI controls while progressbar is activated.

I'll try to show you the pseudo code here:

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener {

                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                BlurTheBackground()
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)


                DoTheLoginStuff()


    }
```

And after Login I want to disable progress bar and reactivate fully UI.

PS: After Login the activity changes to another,but after hitting back button on the smartphone it comes back without refresh

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4409 this library. I think it can help You.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_blurLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.armboldmind.natalipharm.view.customViews.RealtimeBlurView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:realtimeBlurRadius="15dp"
        app:realtimeOverlayColor="#99FFFFFF" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Set it on top of your layout, and on login button click change visibility of progress bar layout.